# Why is the Trådfri Remote obligatory for pairing bulbs with gateway if it uses Zigbee Light Link?

Tags: zigbee, smart-lights, ikea-tradfri

If I understood it correctly, Zigbee Light Link (ZLL) networks function without a coordinator node (as opposed to Zigbee Home Automation networks where it is mandatory). Before I learned that I supposed that the 5-button remote control sold by IKEA plays the role of the coordinator for their Trådfri products because it is possible to control the bulbs directly with it without any other hardware. But since Trådfri is (or at least was) using ZLL, their should not be a coordinator at all. Given that assumption, I was wondering why it is *still* neccessary to bind a new bulb to a remote first before it can be controlled by the Trådfri gateway. Why is it not possible to just use a bulb and the gateway together without a remote control? Is that something vendor-specific that IKEA programmed into the bulbs' firmware? If so, is that a violation of the Zigbee standard or an allowed extension?

Comment: Isn’t the remote only needed to reset the bulb (the so-called touchlink procedure)? If the bulb was bought standalone it should be possible to join an existing network directly. If it was sold with a remote it is probably pre-paired with that remote and you need to reset it before it can join a new network.

Comment: Also, I have to admit I don’t know what the actual setup is in a single remote+bulb pair, but the remote could not possibly be a coordinator: a coordinator needs to listen all the time, so battery powered devices nearly never have that role. On the other hand, the bulb, being powered, could be a coordinator.